# Free memory in C with continuous declarations

Tags: c, linux

If a variable is declared within a loop, does the previous declarations become garbage? For example, in the following:

```
loop{

    int array[10];

    array[i]=......

}
```

`array` is declared for each loop iteration. When it is newly declared, is the new memory location that array allocates same with the older location?. If it is not, does the older declarations become garbage, because the allocated area is not freed? Finally, how can it be freed without exiting the loop if the array is static like the above example?

Comment: It's all fine if you declare `array` outside the loop. The variables "become garbage" outside the scope that they're declared, but their values don't. So what's copied into the array stays there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an automatic variable that the compiler handles - automatically.

You only have to take care of storage you allocate yourself using `new` or `malloc`. The rest is handled for you.

The `array` comes into scope  each time you enter the loop and is destroyed again at the end of each loop. The compiler is very likely to reuse the same space each time, but that is not defined by the language. There will be no garbage either way.

Answer (score 7):

You aren't actually allocating anything. This goes on the stack, and the size of the stack frame is calculated by your compliler at compile time. The array will reuse the same amout of stack space each iteration. The `int array[10]` does effectively nothing at run time.

There's a big difference by doing this:

```
for (...) {
   int a[10];
   a[0] = x;
}
```

and doing this:

```
for (...) {
  int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
  a[0] = x;
  free(a);
}
```

The first "allocation" is fixed in size, and will cost you nothing. The second can be of variable size and will be a heap allocated array which you will need to manually free. C has no concept of garbage collection, so nothing really becomes garbage. But you are required to free whatever you allocate using the `malloc` function. If you never use that function you never need to `free` anything. The compiler will take care of that for you.

Comment: Even though I agree with your answer with full heart, I'm not sure if your terminology will mean anything to someone asking such a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that, for  every iteration of the loop, a new array is created and and its is destroyed at the end of iteration. It implies content of newly created array is undefined .(may be garbage - more chances that it contain same data since it might occupy same place in the stack)

However, internally their wont be any allocation or deallocation for the `int array[10]` as pointed by *Dervall*

Comment: It implies content of newly created array is undefined .(may be garbage - more chances that it contain same data since it might occupy same place in the stack).. This is the exact point I wonder about.